# TSQL - COUNT number of rows in a different state than current row

Tags: t-sql, select, count

It's  kind of hard to explain, but from this example it should be clear.

Table TABLE:

```
 Name  State Time
 --------------------
 A     1     1/4/2012
 B     0     1/3/2012
 C     0     1/2/2012
 D     1     1/1/2012
```

Would like to

```
 select * from TABLE where state=1 order by Time desc
```

plus an additional column 'Skipped' containing the number of rows after one where state=1 in state 0, in other words the output should look like this:

```
Name State Time      Skipped
A    1     1/4/2012  2        -- 2 rows after A where State != 1
D    1     1/1/2012  0        -- 0 rows after D where State != 1
```

0 should also be reported in case of 2 consecutive rows are in state = 1, i.e. there is nothing between these rows in a state other than 1.

It seems like CTE are must here, but can't figure out how to count rows where state != 1.
Any help will be appreciated.

(MS Sql Server 2008)

Answer (score 2):

I've used a CTE to establish RowNo, so that you're not dependent on consecutive dates:

```
WITH CTE_Rows as 
(
    select name,state,time,
    rowno = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [time])
    from MyTable
)
select name,state,time,
    gap = isnull(r.rowno - x.rowno - 1,0)
from
    CTE_Rows r
    outer apply (
        select top 1 rowno 
        from CTE_Rows sub 
        where sub.rowno < r.rowno and sub.state = 1
        order by sub.rowno desc) x
where r.state = 1
```

If you just want to do it by date, then its simpler - just need an `outer apply`:

```
select name,state,r.time,
    gap = convert(int,isnull(r.time - x.time - 1,0))
from
    MyTable r
    outer apply (
        select top 1 time 
        from MyTable sub 
        where sub.time < r.time and sub.state = 1
        order by sub.time desc) x
where r.state = 1
```

FYI the test data is used was created as follows:

```
create table MyTable
(Name char(1), [state] tinyint, [Time] datetime)

insert MyTable 
values
('E',1,'2012-01-05'),
('A',1,'2012-01-04'),
('B',0,'2012-01-03'),
('C',0,'2012-01-02'),
('D',1,'2012-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here you go (it gets a little messy):

```
SELECT U.CurrentTime, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM StateTable AS T3 
        WHERE T3.State=0 
        AND T3.Time BETWEEN U.LastTime AND U.CurrentTime) AS Skipped       
FROM (SELECT T1.Time AS CurrentTime, 
             (SELECT TOP 1 T2.Time 
              FROM StateTable AS T2 
              WHERE T2.Time < T1.Time AND T2.State=1 
              ORDER BY T2.Time DESC) AS LastTime 
      FROM StateTable AS T1 WHERE T1.State = 1) AS U
```